# I am using REST apis with Python. I am getting the a SSL error

Tags: python, rest, ssl, python-requests, python-3.4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.p
y", line 533, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.p
y", line 246, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.p
y", line 738, in _new_conn
    raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL becaus
e the SSL module is not available.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hosts-print.py", line 19, in <module>
    host_count_response = requests.get(host_count_url, verify=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in reques
t
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
is not available.
```

---

My code used to work fine until I added a certificate to Google chrome. I reinstalled python and the requests library, but it the code ran only once. After that the same error repeats.

Comment: You need to point to a `.ca` file manually (add `verify = path_to_ca_file`) or you can disable ssl `verify = false`

Comment: I have disabled ssl by using verify = False. I wasn't getting this error until today. The same code used to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to a `.ca` file manually (add `verify = path_to_ca_file`) or you can disable ssl `verify = false`.

Comment: I have disabled ssl by using verify = False. I wasn't getting this error until today. The same code used to work fine. The error started appearing after I added a certificate to my chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the older versions of Python, and then reinstalling Python as well as the libraries and reinstalling chrome (after deleting cookies, extensions and plug-ins) fixed the issue.